# What is the Linq Query expression to get all the department Id , Name in a select list variable for drop down

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, razor

I am trying  to create the drop down to list the Department name having right to see for the login user.I am passing the userId, DepotIds. The department must be listed against the user and Depot.  My Linq query is not working, please help
I have the following model

```
 public class Depot
{
    public  int Id { get; set; }
    public string  DepotName { get; set; }

}
 public class Department
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string  DepartmentName { get; set; }

}
     
 public class User
{
    public  int Id { get; set; }
    public string  UserName { get; set; }

}
public class USerDepotDepartmentLink
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int DepotId { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public IsDefault { get; set; }
}
```

From the above model I have  the following records

```html
Depot Record
Id = 1; DepotName = Depot1
Id = 2 ; DepotName = Depot2

Department Record
Id = 1; DepartmentName = Sales
Id = 2 ; DepartmentName = Account
Id = 3 ; DepartmentName = Marketing

User Record
Id = 1; Username = User1
Id = 2; Username = User2 

USerDepotDepartmentLink
UserId = 1, DepotId=1, DepartmentId =1 , IsDefault = 1 
UserId = 1, DepotId=1, DepartmentId =2 , IsDefault = 0

UserId = 2, DepotId=1, DepartmentId =2 , IsDefault = 0
UserId = 2, DepotId=1, DepartmentId =3 , IsDefault = 0
UserId = 2, DepotId=2, DepartmentId =1 , IsDefault = 0
UserId = 2, DepotId=2, DepartmentId =2 , IsDefault = 1
UserId = 2, DepotId=2, DepartmentId =3 , IsDefault = 0
```

from the above example for the UserId 1 The dropdown of the Department down list must be 'Sales, Accounts' and selected 'Sales department'

For the userId 2 , the  Department drop down list must be 'Sales, Accounts,Marketing and selected Department is Account.

I created the Linq query given below but not working

```
 public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetLocationsByDepotForDropdown(int userId, int[] depotNo)
    {
        
        List<SelectListItem> locations = (from dpt in goContext.goDepartment
                                          join dep in goContext.goUserDepartment 
                                          on dpt.DepartmentID equals dep.DepartmentID
                                         where dep.UserID == userId
                                         && dpt.IsDeleted == false
                                         select new SelectListItem
                                         {
                                             Value = dpt.DepartmentID.ToString(),
                                             Text = dpt.DepartmentName
                                         }).Where(i => depotNo.Contains(i.Value)).
                                          ToList<SelectListItem>();
        locations.Insert(0, new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = "0",
            Text = "-- Select --"

        });
        return locations;
    }
```

Please help to find the linq query from my example

Comment: What is not working? what is the output of `GetLocationsByDepotForDropdown`? Also, to have a value as selected you should set the property `Selected` of `SelectListItem`.

Comment: The distinct name and Id of the Department against the UserId and int[] DepotId.   I am passing Depot as an integer array . So all the department should be listed with distinct against that user id and Depots. So the result is Departement name and its Id

Comment: For the user id 1 the department name should be listed 'Sales and Accounts' for the userid 2 the department should be  Sales, Accounts, Marketing. I have to give the query condition DepotId in [ int[] Depot] . the Department should be listed against the  parameter integer array  Depots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to the following sample code, you could use GroupBy clause to remove the duplicate records (based on the text and value property), and then check whether the group items contain the selected value (True: IsDefault is 1; False: IsDefault is 0):

```
        var user = "User 2";

        var result = (from udd in usddlist
                      join u in userlist on udd.UserId equals u.Id
                      join d in departmentlist on udd.DepartmentId equals d.Id
                      where u.UserName == user
                      select new
                      {
                          Value = d.Id.ToString(),
                          Text = d.DepartmentName,
                          IsSelected = udd.IsDefault == 1 ? true : false
                      }).GroupBy(c => new { c.Text, c.Value })
              .Select(c =>
              new SelectListItem
              {
                  Value = c.Key.Value,
                  Text = c.Key.Text,
                  Selected = c.Where(d => d.IsSelected == true).ToList().Count == 0 ?false : true
              })
              .Distinct().ToList();
```

The Initial data :

```
       List<Depot> depotlist = new List<Depot>()
        {
            new Depot(){ Id=1, DepotName="Depot 1"},
            new Depot(){ Id=2, DepotName="Depot 2"}
        };

        List<Department> departmentlist = new List<Department>()
        {
            new Department(){ Id=1, DepartmentName="Sales"},
            new Department(){ Id=2, DepartmentName="Account"},
            new Department(){ Id=3, DepartmentName="Marketing"},
        };
        List<User> userlist = new List<User>()
        {
            new User(){ Id=1, UserName="User 1"},
            new User(){ Id=2, UserName="User 2"}
        };

        List<USerDepotDepartmentLink> usddlist = new List<USerDepotDepartmentLink>()
        {
            new USerDepotDepartmentLink(){ UserId = 1, DepotId = 1, DepartmentId = 1,IsDefault=1},
            new USerDepotDepartmentLink(){ UserId = 1, DepotId = 1, DepartmentId = 2,IsDefault=0},
            new USerDepotDepartmentLink(){ UserId = 2, DepotId = 1, DepartmentId = 2,IsDefault=0},
            new USerDepotDepartmentLink(){ UserId = 2, DepotId = 1, DepartmentId = 3,IsDefault=0},
            new USerDepotDepartmentLink(){ UserId = 2, DepotId = 2, DepartmentId = 1,IsDefault=0},
            new USerDepotDepartmentLink(){ UserId = 2, DepotId = 2, DepartmentId = 2,IsDefault=1},
            new USerDepotDepartmentLink(){ UserId = 2, DepotId = 2, DepartmentId = 3,IsDefault=0},
         };
```

After executing the above code, the result as below (the selected Department is Account, Sales and Marketing's Select property is "false"):

[image]

If you want to sort the DropDownlist items, after filter data, you could use [OrderBy() method](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/linq/linq-sorting-operators-orderby-orderbydescending) to sort the SelectList items.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below query which would gives the unique department and also the required option can be selected

```
List<SelectListItem> locations = (from dpt in goContext.goDepartment
                                      join dep in goContext.goUserDepartment
                                      on dpt.Id equals dep.DepartmentId
                                     where dep.UserId == userId && depotNo.Contains(dep.DepotId)
                                     select new
                                     {
                                         DepartmentId = dep.DepartmentId,
                                         DepartmentName = dpt.DepartmentName
                                     }).Distinct()
                                    .Select(s => new SelectListItem
                                     {
                                         Value = s.DepartmentId.ToString(),
                                         Text = s.DepartmentName,
                                         // Selected = write your logic here based on condition
                                     })
                                     .ToList<SelectListItem>();
```